# LSTM autoencoder with Keras data shape issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a model using Keras with LSTM autoencoder. Here what I have tried

```
data = df.values
timesteps = 10
dim = data.shape[1]
samples = data.shape[0]
data.shape = (int(samples/timesteps),timesteps,dim)
```

and then

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(50,input_shape=(timesteps,dim),return_sequences=True))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
```

this is my model fit

```
model.fit(data, data, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(data, data), verbose=0, shuffle=False)
```

This is the error message I am getting

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected lstm_33 to have shape (None, 10, 50) but got array with shape (711, 10, 1)
```

How can I fix this ?

I have only I data set

### Update

input data shape I have  = `(7110, 1)`

This is an Univariate time series data

Comment: On which layer you fail? the first? also post your data.shape, you define `dim = data.shape[1]` but then use it as `data.shape[2]`?

Comment: input shape is `(7110, 1)`

Comment: This isn't specific to your question, but I noticed your error says lstm_33, so that means it is keeping all of your layers from previous runs. If you run `from keras import backend` then `backend.clear_session()` between model builds, then you'll start with a fresh graph and it would start from lstm, lstm_1, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by specifying `input_shape=(timesteps,dim)` for all the layers. You only need to do this for the first layer and the rest will be inferred by the previous layer. What is happening is you are overriding the input shape which is causing the error.

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it